# moq callback makes linq throw exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq

I am using Moq and EF6.

I need to query a table and if there are less than 5 dates in the table I need to add more.

So, I do that in my code:

```
    public void FillPartyList(ObservableCollection<Party> argPartyList)
    {
        argPartyList.Clear();

        using (IPartyTrackerDataAccess localDb = Locator.Resolve<IPartyTrackerDataAccess>())
        {
            InitializeDates(localDb);

            var localList = (from tempList in localDb.Parties
                             where tempList.PartyDate >= DateTime.Now.Date
                             select tempList);

            foreach (Party currentParty in localList)
            {
                argPartyList.Add(currentParty);
            }
        }

    }
```

Inside "InitializeDates" I query the database to see how many dates are there and then add enough to make 5. There are rules around creating the dates [e.g. only on Fri or Sat, etc] so this is not trivial. Then, when the method comes back I get the full list from the database and add it to the parameter.

My problem comes when I try to test this. Here's my test.

```
    public void TestInitializeDates()
    {
        //Expected data
        int callCount = 0;
        int addParty = 0;
        int saveChanges = 0;
        ObservableCollection<Party> PartyList = new ObservableCollection<Party>();

        //Mock data
        IQueryable<Party> partyData = new List<Party>().AsQueryable();
        IQueryable<SystemSetting> settingsData = new List<SystemSetting>().AsQueryable();

        //Setup mock
        Mock<PartyTrackerEntities> mockContext = SetupDbContext();

        SetupApplicationSettings(mockContext, settingsData);
        SetupPartyDbSet(mockContext, partyData);

        Locator.Register<IApplicationSettings, ApplicationSettings>();

        //If I keep the following line I get an exception when querying the "database" for parties.
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Parties.Add(It.IsAny<Party>())).Callback(() => addParty = callCount++);
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.SaveChanges()).Callback(() => saveChanges = callCount++);

        //Run tests

        PartyTrackerModel localModel = new PartyTrackerModel();

        localModel.FillPartyList(PartyList);

        Assert.AreEqual(1, callCount);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, saveChanges);
    }

    private Mock<DbSet<Party>> SetupPartyDbSet(Mock<PartyTrackerEntities> argDbContext, IQueryable<Party> argPartyData)
    {

        //Mock objects
        Mock<DbSet<Party>> mockPartySet = new Mock<DbSet<Party>>();

        mockPartySet.As<IQueryable<Party>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(argPartyData.Provider);
        mockPartySet.As<IQueryable<Party>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(argPartyData.Expression);
        mockPartySet.As<IQueryable<Party>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(argPartyData.ElementType);
        mockPartySet.As<IQueryable<Party>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(argPartyData.GetEnumerator());

        argDbContext.Setup(m => m.Parties).Returns(mockPartySet.Object);

        return mockPartySet;
    }
```

EDIT: I got distracted and didn't finish the question.

Everything works fine until I add the setup that increments a counter, then the Linq in InitializeDates() fails.

How do I increment the counter and leave the DbSet<> mocking properly? How do I query the "database" and still count the calls to Add? If I setup the Context.Parties.Add() to count calls the linq query blows up.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Adding InitializeDates(). Note: None of this has a problem until I add the Moq.Callback.

```
    private static void InitializeDates(IPartyTrackerDataAccess argLocalDb)
    {
        IApplicationSettings localAppSettings = Locator.Resolve<IApplicationSettings>();

        //using (PartyTrackerEntities LocalDb = new PartyTrackerEntities())
        {
            //TODO: Move this code to the PartyTrackerDb class.
            //Technically this would communicate with the database and 
            //make sure there are at least 5 parties in the future.
            var SqlPartyList = from LinqList in argLocalDb.Parties
                               where LinqList.PartyDate >= DateTime.Now.Date
                               select LinqList;
            List<Party> PartyList;
            try
            {
                PartyList = SqlPartyList.OrderByDescending(argOrder => argOrder.PartyDate).Take(5).ToList();
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database. Please ensure that SQLServer is running and accessable from this machine.");
                throw;
            }

            if (PartyList.Count < 5)
            {
                DateTime MaxPartyDate = PartyList.Count <= 0
                                            ? DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1)
                                            : PartyList.Max(argMaxDate => argMaxDate.PartyDate);

                //<= 4 because  PartyList.Count is zero-based so this is 5 parties.
                for (int ShortDayCount = PartyList.Count; ShortDayCount <= 4; ShortDayCount++)
                {
                    int dateOffset;
                    decimal coupleDonation;
                    decimal singleMaleDonation;
                    decimal singleFemaleDonation;
                    decimal sponsoredMaleDonation;
                    if (MaxPartyDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday) //If the last party in the list is on a Friday, then we need to add a Saturday
                    {
                        //Get the Donation amounts
                        //Get Saturday Donations
                        coupleDonation = localAppSettings.SatCoupleDonation;
                        singleMaleDonation = localAppSettings.SatSingleMaleDonation;
                        singleFemaleDonation = localAppSettings.SatSingleFemaleDonation;
                        sponsoredMaleDonation = localAppSettings.SatSponsoredMaleDonation;

                        //Add Sat
                        dateOffset = 1;
                    }
                    else //Otherwise we need to add a Friday
                    {
                        //Get the Donation amounts
                        //Get Friday Donations
                        coupleDonation = localAppSettings.FriCoupleDonation;
                        singleMaleDonation = localAppSettings.FriSingleMaleDonation;
                        singleFemaleDonation = localAppSettings.FriSingleFemaleDonation;
                        sponsoredMaleDonation = localAppSettings.FriSponsoredMaleDonation;

                        if (MaxPartyDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                        {
                            dateOffset = 6;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dateOffset = 5 - (int)MaxPartyDate.DayOfWeek;
                        }
                    }
                    Party NewParty = new Party
                    {
                        PartyDate = MaxPartyDate.AddDays(dateOffset),
                        CoupleDonation = coupleDonation,
                        SingleMaleDonation = singleMaleDonation,
                        SingleFemaleDonation = singleFemaleDonation,
                        SponsoredMaleDonation = sponsoredMaleDonation
                    };

                    argLocalDb.Parties.Add(NewParty);

                    MaxPartyDate = NewParty.PartyDate;
                }

                argLocalDb.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does it blow up?  What's the exception being thrown?

Comment: An exception is thrown at the first linq query the code comes to in InitializeDates(). I can post that too if you think it would help.

Comment: Yes, that would help.